# How can I check two permissions in laravel gates using @can?

Tags: laravel

```
//e.g...
@can('view-post')
// show publish page
@endcan

//something like this.
@can('view-post') OR @can('publish-post')
// show publish page
@endcan
```

If the user have any of the user-rights, then access is granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

> You may also determine if a user is authorized to perform any action from a given array of actions. To accomplish this, use the `@canany` directive:

```
@canany(['update', 'view', 'delete'], $post)
    <!-- The current user can update, view, or delete the post... -->
@elsecanany(['create'], \App\Models\Post::class)
    <!-- The current user can create a post... -->
@endcanany
```

Comment: thanks for this demonstration, it works as I expected. Best approach I think.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in your blade:

```
    @if(Gate::allows('whatever') || Gate::allows('whatever-else'))
    <!-- Code --> 
    @endif
```

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate two different actions, which seems to be OP's ask.

Comment: @ceejayoz It isn't a stretch to add another conditional.

Comment: Sure, but OP was struggling with that, so demonstrating it is helpful. Thanks for doing so.